# Why does mp3lame conversion from mp3float not work for rtmp?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

I am creating a rtmp stream using FFMPEG and sending the data to local NGINX server with the RTMP module.

The originally stream is mp3float, however the conversion to Mp3lame did not work while flv did , how comes?

Doesn't work but no errors

```
fmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel warning -i http://x.x.x.x:8138 -f mp3 rtmp://localhost/live
```

Works with no errors

```
fmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel warning -i http://x.x.x.x:8138 -f flv rtmp://localhost/live
```

Answer (score 1):

Because flv is the only container that is supported by rtmp.